# Return a new object, if the values are same in the object in typescript

Tags: javascript

how can I filter an object and return a new object, which contains all the elements with same values

example:

```
allvalues = {"id1": 3, "id2": 4, "id3": 3}
```

what I accepted is:

```
filteredvalues = {"id1": 3, "id3": 3}
```

because the object key "id1" and "id3" have same value.

this object can be only 3 keys and values.

if there is no shared value, then reutrn a empty object.

any solutions?

Comment: What if you have more than one shared value?

Comment: thx for you comment, I have edited my question, in thsi object can only be 3 keys and values.

Comment: What if there is no shared value? What if all the keys have different values?

Comment: then will return a empty object

Comment: You only ever have 3 possibilities i.e. the 1st value is the same as the 2nd value, the 1st value is the same as the 3rd value or the 2nd value is the same and the 3rd value or all values are the same. It's not too hard to check exhaustively ([`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) might help)

Answer (score 1):

Since the object always contains 3 data

I think it's easier to compare manually

```js
const IsSame = (...data) => {
  return data.every((value, _, array) => value === array[0])
}

const Process = (raw) => {
  const keys = Object.keys(raw)
  const values = Object.values(raw)

  const value = values[0]

  if (IsSame(values[0], values[1], values[2])) return {
    [keys[0]]: value,
    [keys[1]]: value,
    [keys[2]]: value,
  }

  if (IsSame(values[0], values[1])) return {
    [keys[0]]: value,
    [keys[1]]: value,
  }

  if (IsSame(values[0], values[2])) return {
    [keys[0]]: value,
    [keys[2]]: value,
  }

  if (IsSame(values[1], values[2])) return {
    [keys[1]]: value,
    [keys[2]]: value,
  }

  return {}
}

const raw = {
  "id1": 1,
  "id2": 0,
  "id3": 1
}

const result = Process(raw)

console.log(result)
```